# Modules are not being linked in React Native 0.60.5

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I created a new React Native 0.60.5 project using `react-native init`, and added the two modules `react-native-vector-icons` and `react-native-device-info` using `npm i react-native-vector-icons` and `npm i react-native-device-info`, respectively. However, neither `.xcodeproj` file appears in my Libraries folder as they normally would, and nothing changes in my Podfile. I haven't tested out if they work in the actual project yet, but just noticed this unusual behaviour and wanted to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

From React native version >= 0.60  [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) feature is added  , you do not have to run link command .

When you install library using npm/yarn , the library is auto added in pod file and files will not be added in ".xcodeproj"**(it is for project with out pod but in react native >= 0.60 , pod is mandatory)** .

You just have to run this command

```
cd ios && pod instal
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So again, nothing is being added in my Podfile when I install the modules, so I assume running `pod install` won't do anything.